# Weird output after parsing

Tags: c

I have some weird error now, when scanning a bigger file such as this one:

1. 0x1001 0x0001
2. 0x1001 0x0002
3. 0x0004
4. 0x0005
5. 0x0005
6. 0x0005
7. 0x0005
8. 0x0007 0x0001

Im a using this code:

```
 int *inst = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 int *op1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

 FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 char line [32]; // Max line size
 int count=0;

while(fgets (line, sizeof(line),fp) != NULL){
    sscanf(line, "%x" "%x", &inst[count], &op1[count]);
    printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", inst[count],op1[count]);
    count++; }
```

The output is good at the beginning but turns out weird starting from the 7th line showing:

1. 0x1001 0x1
2. 0x1001 0x3
3. 0x4 0x0
4. 0x5 0x0
5. 0x5 0x0
6. 0x5 0x0
7. 0x5 **0x241**
8. 0x1007 0x0

And from that point, if I add more lines to parse everything it gets weirder and weirder.
Am I out of bounds or something?

Comment: I recommend reading character by character with `fgetc()`

Comment: You're allocating exactly *one* `int` in each of the `inst` and `op1` arrays. Which means anything beyond `inst[0]` etc is **undefined behavior**. You need to expand your allocated arrays with each *successful* pair read.

Comment: Check the `malloc` you are not allocating enough space

Comment: it looks to me like your line 2 is wrong also

Comment: You allocated enough space for one int each for `inst` and `op1` but you're trying to read in an entire array of `int` into each.

Comment: how does this code not segfault?

Comment: `int *inst = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` is wrong in at least two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of issues

1. Big: Not allocating memory.
2. Not using the result of `sscanf()`
3. Not opening the file in text mode

Suggest:

```
// Instead of 8, make 2 passes to find the number of lines or reallocate as you go.
int *inst = calloc(8, sizeof(*inst));  /
// calloc initializes to 0, nice as your various lines don't always have 2 numbers.
int *op1 = calloc(8, sizeof(*op1));
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
...
int result = sscanf(line, "%x" "%x", &inst[count], &op1[count]);
switch (result) {
  case 1: printf("0x%x\n", inst[count]); break;
  case 2: printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", inst[count],op1[count]); break;
  default: ; // handle error
}
```

Comment: Personally, I like `0x%X` style in `printf()`.  Further, maybe use `0x%04X` for alignment.